# How to match phrase between words

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to only capture **user-context** from the code block below. So in a nutshell I want everything between repo_ and _tag Please send examples.

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`repo_(.*)_tag`)
    var str = `#gitflow
variable "repo_user-context_tag" {
  default = "blah"
}

#gitflow
variable "repo_user-office_tag" {
  default = "blah"
}
`

    for _, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match)
    }
}
```

Output:
repo_user-context_tag
repo_user-office_tag

Comment: Is this really a golang based question? If its just the regex, you can use a capture group like so `repo_(.*)_tag`

Comment: yes. I would like to pass the regex into a golang regex func like```FindStringSubmatch```

Comment: Note that the language is called simply "Go".  "Golang" is used for search disambiguation. Never is "go-lang" the proper term.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/BVmtt0J5Ns2 , the output is repo_go-lang_tag. I would like to just have go-lang.

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title. They're redundant noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your regexp. The problem is that you're using the wrong function to see the substring match you're looking for.

Instead of `FindAllString`, you need [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch):

```golang
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`repo_(.*)_tag`)
    var str = `#gitflow
variable "repo_user-context_tag" {
  default = "blah"
}

#gitflow
variable "repo_user-office_tag" {
  default = "blah"
}
`

    for _, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match[1])
    }
}
```

See it [on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YWygNoEET7W).

Output:

```
user-context
user-office
```